# How to assign html input a variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a calendar and i have it so that you can change the month and year and the days will change with it. I want to make it so that the user can input the month and year in a form or something like that and give it a variable so i can make the calendar adjust with it. 
[This is what i have](http://codepen.io/Mr_Trystar/pen/qRZQRM)

```
 Month <input type="number" id="monthInput" >
<br>
 Year <input type="number" id="yearInput" >
```

Comment: Can you give a little more info? I can see what you did in codepen, but I don't see the form/input you want to "assign a variable" to.

Comment: not possible with your static code

Comment: there at the very bottom

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it

```
<form id="form1">
  Month: <input name="month" type="number" size="20">
  <br>
  Year: <input name="year" type="number" size="20">
</form>
  <br>
<button onclick = "myFunction()">Submit</button>

<script>
function myFunction(){
var x,y,m;
    x = document.getElementById("form1");
    m = x.elements["month"].value;
    y = x.elements["year"].value;
}
```

so m is the input for month and y would give you the input for month